# Pull to refresh package in flutter for pagination purpose

Tags: flutter

Hello Readers I am new in flutter and i want to do pagination, for pagination I am using one package which name is  "pull to refersh".
Problems :
I have total 6 post and per page limits are 3.
1)When I reached at the end of list then api will call and set current page variable value is 2 and it will load all data of page 2 as a new list, but i want to merge page 2 data into same list... (Pagination like facebook instagram etc).
2)My another problem is when i pull for refersh, page is refersh perfectly and it will go to the first page but problem is, when i again go at the end of list it shows me no more data(which means page 2 api is not working)
I have one condition like if else:- "hasNextPage" this variable getting from api and the response is 1 or 2, if response is 1 then there further page after current page and if is 0 then there is no page after current page.

I am posting my code and api link also can you please help me.

Method for get data from API

```
int currentPage = 1;
bool isRefersh = false;
final RefreshController refreshController = RefreshController();

Future<UserPost> getUserPost() async {

    var url =
        "LINK=$currentPage";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsondata = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    var _apiData = UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("******getUserPost API");

      print("current page****$currentPage");
      print("hasnext page ${_apiData.hasNextPage}");

      print(jsondata);
      if(isRefersh == true){
        setState((){
          //currentPage = 1;
          isRefersh = false;
        });
        refreshController.refreshCompleted();
        return UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);
      }
      else{
        print("//////////////// has next page");
        print(_apiData.hasNextPage.toString());
        if(_apiData.hasNextPage == 0){
          refreshController.loadNoData();
          return UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);
        }else{
        }
        return UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);
      }

    } else {
      return UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);
    }
  }
```

Method for pull to Refersh

```
onRefresh: () async{
                await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
                  setState(() {
                  isRefersh = true;
                  currentPage = 1;
                        });
             },
```

Method for Pagination

```
onLoading: () async {
                if(snapshot.data!.hasNextPage == 0){
                 refreshController.loadNoData();
                 }else{
                  setState(() {
                  currentPage++;
                         });
                            await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
                            refreshController.loadComplete();
                          }

                        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

when you get the response in second page just create new list with previous list.

i.e  var newData = [...?dummyData.data, ...?_apiData.data];

than return this same list.

```
  UserPostModel dummyData = UserPostModel();

  Future<UserPostModel> getUserPost() async {
    var url =
        "*****?page=$currentPage";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsondata = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    var _apiData = UserPostModel.fromJson(jsondata);

    var newData = [...?dummyData.data, ...?_apiData.data];

    //totalPage = _apiData.totalPages as int?;

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if (isRefersh == true) {
        setState(() {
          isRefersh = false;
        });
        refreshController.refreshCompleted();
      } else {
        if (_apiData.hasNextPage == 0) {
          refreshController.loadNoData();
        } else {
          refreshController.loadComplete();
        }
      }
      dummyData.data = newData;

      return dummyData;
    } else {
      return dummyData;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I Hope it's help you

try this way :-

```
final RefreshController refreshController =
  RefreshController(initialRefresh: true);



 Future<bool> getPassengerData({bool isRefresh = false}) async {
    if (isRefresh) {
      currentPage = 1;
    } else {
      if (currentPage >= totalPages) {
        refreshController.loadNoData();
        return false;
      }
    }

    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(
        "api url=$currentPage&size=10");

    final response = await http.get(uri);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result = passengersDataFromJson(response.body);

      if (isRefresh) {
        passengers = result.data;
      }else{
        passengers.addAll(result.data);
      }

      currentPage++;

      totalPages = result.totalPages;

      print(response.body);
      setState(() {});
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Method for pull to Refersh

```
onRefresh: () async {
          final result = await getPassengerData(isRefresh: true);
          if (result) {
            refreshController.refreshCompleted();
          } else {
            refreshController.refreshFailed();
          }
        },
```

Method for onLoading:

```
 onLoading: () async {
          final result = await getPassengerData();
          if (result) {
            refreshController.loadComplete();
          } else {
            refreshController.loadFailed();
          }
        },
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually I have different model class from this. I want to know one thing, this whole code of mine there is no array. If i don't have array then how to append? (List.addall())??? Please suggest me how to append data to the list.

Comment: can you share your full screen code so  I am easily  solve your problem

Comment: In that code i was not used any array, i used just snapshot and with the help of snapshot i  am accessing my api data. can you please suggest me how to used array instead of snapshot

Comment: you used **passengers** this is a list and in my code i am not using list just i work with snapshot.data so can you please tell me in this case how i can add.all method use??